# Can i use one GCM project number in two different app for receive Push of GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We have two different application but both required same push notification from Google Cloud Messages and i have use only one sender id (Project No of Enable one of Google Console )in both app .

Do this will create any issue because i am getting two push for same message in my one of the application.

Comment: if your both application  package name is same than no problem if diff than u know gcm is also work with package name

Comment: Yes you can but you must create keys for different packages under GCM project id

Comment: @koutuk if i use different project number for each app then also i need to use different Api key at server end right ?

Comment: right dude you got my point

Comment: @koutuk ohh let me start work on it Thanks..

Comment: Why need another api key? The api key is used when my GCM server send data to Google GCM connection server. I think as long as my GCM server can manage client registration id and package name mapping well, I can use the same api key. PS. I'm planning to do same thing, but not yet done, this is just my thought, if wrong, please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: @正宗白布鞋 Please try that you may get wried behavior in getting push on both app as they are using same sender id and server using same api from that GCM enable project.

Comment: Thanks your reminder. I will keep that in mind and try that later, but not very soon. When I have some result, I will come back.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the question? I followed this link: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html Do I have to write something before call "gcm.register(SENDER_ID);"?

Answer (score 2):

Simply restrict your notification by package name:

```
Sender sender = new Sender(KEY);
GCMessage msg = new GCMessage.Builder().
restrictedPackageName(GC_PACKAGE_NAME).build();
```

Comment: You mean so say this i need to apply on my server side from where pushes are send to GCM cloud link Right ?

Comment: @casten i just want to say that for server side we are using php script so your code might not use full in my case ,any way we have written different script of each app with different server api key. and it is working fine.